# Python if statement using Modulo

Tags: python, if-statement

I made a list called 'l' then I created a for loop with an if statement inside.  The if statement is suppose to check if num is even (equal to 0) if it is then it will print the num if not it will print "Odd number".

Why does the first one print incorrectly ( 2 4 Odd number! )
and the second one prints correctly ( Odd number 2 Odd number 4 Odd number )

I already tried changing the spacing on the first one but I kept getting statement exceptions.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# First

for num in l:
if num % 2 == 0:
    print num
else:
print 'Odd number!'

print
print

#Second

for num in l:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print num
    else:
        print 'Odd number!'
```

Output:

## First

```
2
4
Odd number!
```

## Second

```
Odd number!
2
Odd number!
4
Odd number!
```

Comment: indentation isn't optional in Python `if` statements and `for` loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation. Python uses indentation to figure out scopes in your code, so for your first for loop, it doesn't do anything. Reformat it like this:

```
for num in l:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print num
    else:
        print 'Odd number!'
```

The second piece of code was properly indented, that's why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Python cares about how much whitespace is at the start of a line. This line:

```
if num % 2 == 0:
```

is not being considered as part of the for loop.